# How to get a Prefect flow to run inside a conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, prefect

I'm new to Prefect and I'm trying to get my flow to run inside a conda environment. I'm trying to follow the yaml manifest deployment outlined here:

https://discourse.prefect.io/t/how-to-run-my-deployment-in-a-virtual-environment-such-as-conda/1423

I have 2 conda environments, the Prefect server just running under a conda environment called  `prefect` (only has Prefect installed) and I have an environment called `flow-test` that the flow should be running in (has prefect and pandas installed).

My manifest yaml looks like:

```yaml
### hello-deployment.yaml
###
### A complete description of a Prefect Deployment for flow 'hello'
###
name: my-flow-deployment
description: null
version: 84cb14085d1234c5cf60c13e352b0c9e
# The work queue that will handle this deployment's runs
work_queue_name: my-queue
work_pool_name: my-process-pool
tags: []
parameters: {}
schedule: null
is_schedule_active: null
infra_overrides: {}
infrastructure:
  type: process
  env: {}
  labels: {}
  name: null
  command:
    - conda
    - run
    - -n
    - flow-test
    - python
    - -m
    - prefect.engine
  stream_output: true
  working_dir: null
  block_type_slug: process
  _block_type_slug: process

###
### DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
###
flow_name: hello
manifest_path: null
storage: null
path: C:\Users\{MY_USER_NAME}\Documents\prefect\flows\hello
entrypoint: hello.py:hello
parameter_openapi_schema:
  title: Parameters
  type: object
  properties:
    name:
      title: name
      position: 0
      type: string
  required:
    - name
  definitions: null
timestamp: "2023-07-26T14:04:25.905180+00:00"
triggers: []
```

I deploy this using `prefect deployment apply ./hello-deployment.yaml` from inside the `prefect` environment.

My `hello.py` looks like:

```py
import datetime
from prefect import flow
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay


@flow(log_prints=True)
def hello(name: str):
    print(f"Hello {name}, yesterday was {(datetime.datetime.today() - BDay(1)).strftime(r'%Y-%m-%d')}!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello(name="John Smith")
```

When I trigger this flow from the UI I'm getting the error:

```
Flow could not be retrieved from deployment.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\{MY_USER_NAME}\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3eia6u6vprefect\hello.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

...

prefect.exceptions.ScriptError: Script at 'hello.py' encountered an exception: ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'pandas'")
03:54:57 PM
prefect.flow_runs
Process 17228 exited cleanly.
```

I've verified that if a activate the conda environment `flow-test` and run python that I can import pandas without issue. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though this is not possible:

https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/issues/7379

You can however run multiple agents with multiple conda environments which is the approach I will be going with.